# Treat long Numbers as Strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, biginteger

I am getting a long number (644577696667403013) as an argument via argv._[] in a javascript CLI script.

I can't find a way to interpret this number as a string, it always gets converted (to '644577696667402900'). I tried BigInt und BigNumber, but what I need is not a number, I just need a string.

Please give me a hint, thank you so much!
Matthias

Big Number / BigInt

```
var big = new BigNumber(argv._[1]); // skript 644577696667403013
console.dir(big.toString());
```

--> '644577696667402900'

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript

Comment: Try: `big.toFixed()`

Comment: What is the data type of argv._[1] this argument value??

Comment: Yes is Javascript(Node 10). big.toFixed() yields same ( '644577696667402900'). typof argv._[1] is number

Comment: my workaround is to pass _ 644577696667403013 as argument and then .slice(1) it, but...

Comment: I think the issue is with how you are using the BigInt or BigNumber constructors. You shouldn't be passing a number that exceeds the max int size, since then it is automatically truncated before it even hits the constructor. For example, for BigInt, you can pass the number as a string literal, `(BigInt('644577696667403013')).toString()`, or with 'n' appended to a integer literal, `(BigInt(644577696667403013n)).toString()`. Both preserve the original full integer.